# Methods not called when instantiating a new class

Tags: c++, pointers, namespaces

In Dog.cpp, I have this macro outside the class scope:

```
BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(Dog)
    MAP_SETPARAM(eParam_Macro_Eat,      Eat)
    MAP_SETPARAM(eParam_Macro_Walk,     Walk)
    MAP_SETPARAM(eParam_Macro_Sleep,    Sleep)
END_GETPARAM_MAP(Dog)

class Dog : public Animal
{
   HRESULT init()
   {
      //When using this, macros above are not called (BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP, MAP_SETPARAM and END_GETPARAM_MAP)
      auto animal = std::make_unique<Animal>();
      animal->Init();

     //But when directly calling the method via a namespace, the macros were being called
    //Animal::Init();
   }
};
```

The implementation of the macros is in Animals.hpp:

```
class Animal
{
public:
   HRESULT Init()
   {
      //some implementation
      return S_OK;
   }

protected:
   HRESULT  MapSetParamHandler(ULONG paramId, ParamValueHandler handler);
   virtual void SetupSetParamMap(void) {}
};

#define BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(className)   void className::SetupSetParamMap(void) {typedef className ThisClass;
#define MAP_SETPARAM(paramId, handler)  MapSetParamHandler(paramId, static_cast<ParamValueHandler>(&ThisClass::handler));
#define END_SETPARAM_MAP(className)     }
```

Any idea why the macros are not called when using the first implmentation? I have also tried the following but all do not call the macros:

```
Animal animal;
animal.Init();
//----
Animal* animal = new Animal;
animal->Init();
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: `std::make_unique<Animal>()` creates a brand new `Animal` object, without any relation to the `Dog` object the `init` function is called on.

Comment: Also `init` and `Init`? That's going to be a good source of confusion.

Comment: This isn't valid. `BEGIN_SETPARAM_MAP(Dog)` expands to `void Dog::SetupSetParamMap(void) {`... before `Dog` has been defined.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude totally made sense! It is clear to me now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you want to make abstract class `Animal`. To make it, declare `SetupSetParamMap` pure virtual. I.e. `virtual void SetupSetParamMap(void) = 0;`

Currently, your `Animal` class is not abstract and you create it directly. `Animal` has an empty implementation of `SetupSetParamMap` method and this method is called. You have to create `Dog`

```cpp
Animal* animal = new Dog;
animal->Init();
```

**Added**
Also, as @aschepler said, you call macros before even the class and its methods declaration. Add `MapSetParamHandler` method declaration in `Dog` class and move macros call after class declaration